# How can I modify my C code to replace words in a file without user input?

Tags: c, string

```
/**
 * C program to find and replace all occurrences of a word in file.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

/* Function declaration */
void replaceAll(char *str, const char *oldWord, const char *newWord);


int main()
{
/* File pointer to hold reference of input file */
FILE * fPtr;
FILE * fTemp;
char path[100];

char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
char oldWord[100], newWord[100];


printf("Enter path of source file: ");
scanf("%s", path);

printf("Enter word to replace: ");
scanf("%s", oldWord);

printf("Replace '%s' with: ");
scanf("%s", newWord);


/*  Open all required files */
fPtr  = fopen(path, "r");
fTemp = fopen("replace.tmp", "w"); 

/* fopen() return NULL if unable to open file in given mode. */
if (fPtr == NULL || fTemp == NULL)
{
    /* Unable to open file hence exit */
    printf("\nUnable to open file.\n");
    printf("Please check whether file exists and you have read/write privilege.\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


/*
 * Read line from source file and write to destination 
 * file after replacing given word.
 */
while ((fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fPtr)) != NULL)
{
    // Replace all occurrence of word from current line
    replaceAll(buffer, oldWord, newWord);

    // After replacing write it to temp file.
    fputs(buffer, fTemp);
}


/* Close all files to release resource */
fclose(fPtr);
fclose(fTemp);


/* Delete original source file */
remove(path);

/* Rename temp file as original file */
rename("replace.tmp", path);

printf("\nSuccessfully replaced all occurrences of '%s' with '%s'.", oldWord, newWord);

return 0;
}



/**
 * Replace all occurrences of a given a word in string.
 */
void replaceAll(char *str, const char *oldWord, const char *newWord)
{
char *pos, temp[BUFFER_SIZE];
int index = 0;
int owlen;

owlen = strlen(oldWord);

// Fix: If oldWord and newWord are same it goes to infinite loop
if (!strcmp(oldWord, newWord)) {
    return;
}


/*
 * Repeat till all occurrences are replaced. 
 */
while ((pos = strstr(str, oldWord)) != NULL)
{
    // Backup current line
    strcpy(temp, str);

    // Index of current found word
    index = pos - str;

    // Terminate str after word found index
    str[index] = '\0';

    // Concatenate str with new word 
    strcat(str, newWord);
    
    // Concatenate str with remaining words after 
    // oldword found index.
    strcat(str, temp + index + owlen);
}
}
```

I have that code in C which can change all "oldWords" into "newWords". Works fine, but everytime I want to change the code to change the words on its own I'm completely stupid. I want that I don't have to put the words that have to change into the console, but I want to have them in the code. I just want to tell the console the path of the source file and that's it.

Would be nice if you could help me with some examples like Hello to Bye and Morning to Night.

Comment: You should get used to apply some proper indentation. It makes your code much more readable.

Comment: Not related to the question, but if `newWord` is longer than `oldWord` you will overrun your buffer. If replacing `oldWord` with `newWord` creates a new occurance of `oldWord`, this will also be replaced. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Yeah i just recognized that you need to write the code in a special way in here, so i just slammed on the spacebar so it works.
I have a indentation in my code on the raspberry pie. But your right yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to take `oldWord` and `newWord` from user input, you can define them as constants in the code:

```c
const char* oldWord = "Hello";
const char* newWord = "Bye";
```

Comment: I dont know why there was such a blockade in my head...
Changed everything and thought it would be more complicated.
I just have to figure out now how i can change some special lines in the program.
For example:

The previous file has the code F450 and F1200. That should turn to v=0.45 and v=1.2, so i cant just tell the programm that it should change F to v=0., because F1200 would change to v=0.12 and that would be stupid. Any idea?

Comment: @Maxv1n you would need to change `F450` to `v=0.45`, not only the `F` alone. And anyway, you will run into the problem I already mentioned in my comment below your question. If the replacement text is longer than the replaced text, you may overrun your buffer.